# Basic CDN with Nginx or HA proxy to serve static content?

Tags: nginx, redirect, cdn, high-availability

I have 2 servers A & B. On both server I serve static content via Nginx.

I would like to set up a HTTP redirection on A (Nginx, Ha proxy, Varnish ?) that check health of A & B and redirect HTTP requests to both servers depending on their availibility. Later the "balancer" will be on a separate dedicated server.

Actually I thought upstream from nginx would do the trick but all the bandwidth go throught this proxy which is not what. 
I want to use all available bandwidth from A & B so I have to redirect request on A & B servers.

**My searches:**

HA Proxy have a HTTP redirection wich may help me  : https://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/http_redirection.html . Maybe using with https://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/healthchecks.html to always send to available server. This mean installing and managing a new app I'm not familiar with (HA proxy).

There is mix with some perl code and nginx to achieve that here: http://www.sourceprojects.org/nginx-stateless-loadbalancer but It use external perl script and I'm not sure it is very robust solution.

I wonder if there is something I missed in Nginx or Varnish to achieve that ?